# Почему не грузятся SVG картинки без сервера?

Tags: javascript, svg

Когда запущен сервер - всё отлично, когда открываю на локалке просто `index.html`, то выпадают ошибки.

> Unsafe attempt to load URL file:///D:/17.dir/dir1/build/sprites.svg#camera from frame with URL file:///D:/17.dir/dir1/build/index.html. 'file:' URLs are treated as unique security origins.

Comment: Потому-что путь абсолютный.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

По сообщению об ошибке видно, что вы пытались вызвать изображение из спрайта svg. 
Вероятнее всего у вас браузер `Chrome` или другой браузер из семейства `webkit`
Эти  браузеры не работают, если файл спрайта находится локально.

Если нужно проверить на локалке запускайте `Firefox`

Comment: Именно, вроде бы в чате это обсуждали=)

Comment: @Arthur да, обсуждали, но его в нашем чате не было :) И раз пытался запустить локально, значит, что-то нужно было проверить, вот и совет дал, нужно проверить локально,- используй Firefox

Answer (score 3):

Ваша ошибка возникает из-за нарушения правил `CORS` ([Cross-origin resource sharing](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)).

Если нужно, чтобы работало везде, то делайте через [Data:URL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data:_URL). Обойти эти правила для локальных файлов можно только так.

Так можно через `JS` свободно грузить картинки `SVG`:

```js
var img = new Image;
img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa('<svg version="1.2" width="5.64mm" height="5.64mm" viewBox="0 0 564 564" stroke-width="28.222" stroke-linejoin="round" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><g id="id3" transform="translate(125 125)"><path fill="rgb(0,102,204)" stroke="none" d="M 380,246 C 380,255 376,263 369,269 362,276 355,279 346,279 L 253,279 C 253,290 257,304 266,321 274,339 279,353 279,364 279,381 276,394 270,402 264,410 253,414 236,414 232,410 228,402 226,392 224,381 222,370 218,359 215,347 210,338 203,330 199,326 137,249 134,247 130,246 110,246 110,246 L 110,77 C 110,77 124,77 127,77 130,76 160,67 164,66 168,64 239,44 262,44 L 294,44 C 327,44 336,64 344,88 345,91 380,240 380,246 Z M 413,246 C 413,230 384,108 382,98 377,86 370,45 355,31 340,17 320,10 296,10 L 262,10 C 245,10 228,12 212,16 195,20 176,26 155,33 134,40 122,44 118,44 118,44 21,47 15,54 8,60 9,267 16,274 22,280 115,279 115,279 121,284 170,345 179,354 183,358 193,398 196,410 200,421 205,431 213,438 220,445 227,448 236,448 251,448 264,445 276,439 288,434 297,425 303,413 309,400 312,384 312,364 312,347 308,330 300,313 L 346,313 C 364,313 380,306 393,293 407,280 413,264 413,246 Z"/></g></svg>');

document.write('CORS – ');
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать почему так. Через js не подходит вариант

Comment: @РомаХр, а как нужно? Напишите, пожалуйста, так, чтобы я мог не гадать что вам нужно.

Comment: Весь html написан через Pug, т.к. использую сборщик, то напрямую svg не подключатся ввиду своей громоздкости, создается отдельный файл sprites.svg, оттуда уже подтягивается по id нужный svg. Я решил проблему просто - все же переписал svg со всеми вложенностями в Pug.  Т.к. сборщик используется для сайтов с админкой, то данные пути, я думаю, работали бы.

Comment: Ну и выходит, что тут уже вопросы к сборщику, что не является сутью вопроса данной темы

Comment: @Bharata вот поэтому фрагменту из сообщения об ошибке `sprites.svg#camera` видно, что была попытка вызвать из спрайта по ID изображение camera  Chrome накладывает ограничение по вызову при локальном размещении спрайта. И тут и JS не поможет, будет просто другое сообщение об ошибке

Answer (score 1):

Ответ нашла в книге Using SVG with CSS3 and HTML5, раздел [Understanding CORS and SVG](https://oreillymedia.github.io/Using_SVG/extras/ch10-cors.html).

Тут подробно объясняют:

Many SVG features that use external files do more than just embed them like an image. The referenced SVG file interacts with the current document in ways that can’t easily be shielded from scripts. This includes  element clones and also graphical effects like filters, masks, and clipping paths. Since the SVG document from the other origin could have (theoretically) been customized based on private data, they are subject to cross-origin limitations.

If you want to use SVG  references to an asset file that you host on a different web domain then your main web pages, the only solution (currently) is JavaScript. A JavaScript XMLHTTPRequest or fetch request can download the file—with cross-origin headers—and inject the markup into your page, where the SVG renderer can access it.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).